# How to search expenses for current user with Searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

In my Expense Manager app, in the expenses_controler.rb:

```
current_user.expenses.order('date DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(8).search(params[:search])
```

the **current_user.expenses** stands for nothing since the params[:search] has access to every expense (the whole database).

I tried with .search(params[:search], user_id: current_user.id), but it doesn't work.

How can I add a filter to list only items for the logged in user? The current_user method is method from Devise and it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Expense.search params[:search], where: {user_id: current_user.id}
```